# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Cannot Insert Duplicate Primary Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, primary-key

I am generating user Id in this way from controller

```
long lastUserId = 0;

var userProfile = from m in db.UserProfiles select m;
userProfile = userProfile.Where(s => s.DbType == "OFFLINE");

foreach (var c in userProfile)
{
   lastUserId = c.UserId;
}

if (lastUserId != 0)
{
   lastUserId = lastUserId + 1;
}
else
{
   lastUserId = 1000001;
}
```

When any two person register at same time and hit the controller I am getting the error of key violation now what to do?

Comment: You can use GUID instead of long lastUserId

Comment: If you can, let the database handle this. Use an `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server, or a `SEQUENCE` in Oracle to have unique values for each request

Answer (score 1):

Use a **GUID** for the Id or make the **ID field Auto increment** by taking BigInt at database and let Database to handle this.

```
Guid lastUserId;
var userProfile = from m in db.UserProfiles select m;
userProfile = userProfile.Where(s => s.DbType == "OFFLINE");

foreach (var c in userProfile)
{
   lastUserId = c.UserId;
}

if (your condition)
{
   lastUserId = new Guid();
}
```

Comment: I can't use BigInt as i want Unique Id to be Build According To my Need

Comment: Then change the db column to Unique identifier (Sql Server) and use Guid.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment that you can't use bigint due to a need?

Comment: getting error in lastMessagesId = c.MessageId; Error: cannot convert long to guid...

Comment: you have to change the database field to UniqueIdentifier in Database

Comment: and also  GUID is 16 bytes long. A "long" is often understood as being 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes) long. You cannot convert between those without losing or providing extra data.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest use primary key on that column that have `IDENTITY`, So you don't need to check.

```
if (lastUserId != 0)
{
   lastUserId = lastUserId + 1;
}
else
{
   lastUserId = 1000001;
}
```

It will automatically increase the value from the last one.

**you can also define IDENTITY should be start from XYZ number and increase by 1 or as you want.**

*Each database support the IDENTITY feature.*

Comment: I cant use BigInt as i want Unique Id to be Build According To my Need

Comment: Yes you can do the same using bigint db

Answer (score 0):

Use a GUID for the Id if generating the identifier in code

or

Use your database...  if you must use long type then the identifier field should be an auto-incrementing primary key which creates the unique numeric value at insertion (BIGINT type value for SQL Server.)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
static long lastUserId = 0;
```